# Javascript 2-dimensional arrays straight from MySQL query via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a mysql table with 5 columns (ID,timestamp_day,dayprice,weekprice,weekendprice), in this table the prices are stored for the next 3 year for day,weekend and week rental. The prices are not always the same, in fact they can be different per day (that’s why I store the per day). 
Now I want the user to select a rentalperiod in a dropdown (week,weekend,day) and than display weeknumbers with the prices for the selected rental term, for a selected date range of  3 months. My idea is to make an (2-dimensional?) arrays with the all the timestamp for 3 year with the prices per rental term, so I can make a function in jquery that displays the prices based on the changing user input. The advantage is that I only have to use one query for each advertisement, and not a new query for each change of the user.
But is there a way to produce these 3 javascript arrays with one query, together with the rest of the data? The simpyfied query now looks like this:

SELECT * FROM data_adv INNER JOIN data_pictures ON data_adv.ID = data_pictures.ID WHERE adv_nr = 10

Answer (score 0):

If you need multidimensional arrays I would format them in JSON in PHP and then return them in that format to javascript/Jquery, where using them is quite easy.

Also I wouldn't do a query that returns 3 years of information... Maybe get 1 month each time or so, no user is going to look over 3 years of rentals :S